# USE INSERT INTO WITH A SELECT STATEMENT AND A STRING VALUE

Tags: mysql

I need to do the following:

```
insert orders (id, currency, ordvalue)
select item_id, 'USD', ordvalue  
from orderitems 
where item_id=2;
```

So in my case I need to insert USD as a fixed value - is this possible? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you tried running this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Do you want to have a *default* value for `currency` as *USD* no matter what row you insert on `orders`?

Comment: Thank you and yes I would like to have USD no matter what row I insert....

Answer (score 1):

[***MySQL's trigger***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) support action time for execution. You can use `BEFORE INSERT` to set a default value for the field like this:

### Trigger:

```
USE `test`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test.orders_BEFORE_INSERT$$
USE `test`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`orders_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

SET NEW.currency='USD';

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

### Test:

```
mysql> USE `test`;
Database changed
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test.orders_BEFORE_INSERT$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `test`$$
Database changed
mysql> CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`orders_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> 
    -> SET NEW.currency='USD';
    -> 
    -> END
    -> $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> INSERT INTO test.orders(id,ordvalue)
    -> VALUES(1,40);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.orders;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | currency | ordvalue |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | USD      | 40       |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Or you can assign a default value in the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`orders` 
CHANGE COLUMN `currency` `currency` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT 'USD';
```

### Test 2:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.orders;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | currency | ordvalue |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | USD      | 40       |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> ALTER TABLE `test`.`orders`  CHANGE COLUMN `currency` `currency` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT 'USD';
Query OK, 1 rows affected (0.38 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test.orders_BEFORE_INSERT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test.orders(id,ordvalue)
    -> VALUES(2,60),(3,50);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test.orders;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | currency | ordvalue |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | USD      | 40       |
|  2 | USD      | 60       |
|  3 | USD      | 50       |
+----+----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Note: this will work only if you don't use `currency` in your insert statements.*

### Test 3:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test.orders(id,currency,ordvalue) VALUES(5,'',60),(4,'',50);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test.orders;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | currency | ordvalue |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | USD      | 40       |
|  2 | USD      | 60       |
|  3 | USD      | 50       |
|  4 |          | 50       |
|  5 |          | 60       |
+----+----------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test.orders(id,currency,ordvalue) VALUES(6,null,50);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test.orders;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | currency | ordvalue |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | USD      | 40       |
|  2 | USD      | 60       |
|  3 | USD      | 50       |
|  4 |          | 50       |
|  5 |          | 60       |
|  6 | NULL     | 50       |
+----+----------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```